# c# create unmanaged object* array

Tags: c#, arrays, object, unmanaged

i need to create a variable length array of unmanaged object, but i need the array to be unmanaged too, so i can't use List<> or other classes but i have to malloc/realloc it in the c way.

this is my code:

```
unsafe class A{
    unsafe private int a1, a2;
    unsafe public byte* arr;
}
```

and on a different class method i would like to do something like this:

```
private unsafe A* arr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(array_size * Marshal.SizeOf<A>());
```

Now i these questions:

1. How to convert IntPtr to A*? **OR** does exist a proper c# malloc/realloc
   function? **OR** if i .dll import the real c/c++ realloc function would
   be safe to use it?
2. How do i get a A* pointer to an A unmanaged object? if i try with '&' it says "cannot take the adress of [...] a managed object" but it shouldn't be managed. Am I doing something wrong in class declaration?

optional: why sizeof(A) doesn't work but Marshal.SizeOf() it's fine?

Comment: various performance reason but just on a small piece of code of critical value, mostly to use memcpy imported .dll.

I started my project in c# believing that unsafe c# was the same as pure c, now i know i'm wrong but i don't want to rewrite my entire program.

Comment: Your `A` is not unmanaged, it's just regular .NET class (marking it with "unsafe" keyword doesn't change anything, and is redundant).

Comment: @evk so how i do creeate a unmanaged A object?

Comment: @Slai for the same exact code i posted i receive compiling error in VS 2017, did you changed something?

Comment: @DamianoDiVincenzo you can't. nothing short of writing some c/c++ code and than marshaling it to .net world.

Comment: sorry never mind .. I had to change `class` to `struct` and made `unsafe void Main() { sizeof(A).Dump(); }` in LINQPad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use C# class for such things, but you can use struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct A
{
    public int A1;
    public int A2;
}

int array_size = 5;
// just cast IntPtr to A*
A* arr = (A*) Marshal.AllocHGlobal(array_size * Marshal.SizeOf<A>());
// set first element of unmanaged array
arr[0] = new A {A1 = 1, A2 = 2};
// set second
arr[1] = new A {A1 = 3, A2 = 4};

// alternative syntax:
// set first element
*arr = new A { A1 = 5, A2 = 6 };
// set second element
*(arr + 1) = new A { A1 = 5, A2 = 6 };
// get first element
var first = *arr;
var second = *(arr + 1);
Console.WriteLine(first.A1 + " " + first.A2);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)arr);
```

Comment: this works but it's on the stack, isn't it possible to do that on the heap?

Comment: @DamianoDiVincenzo it's not on the stack - it's in unmanaged memory you allocated with `AllocHGlobal'. Or you mean something different?

Comment: i think you are right.
sorry, i got confused by the "struct" that usually are on the stack, but in this case i suppose it should be allocated inside the pointer area.